# Show: least squares estimator of $\theta_1$ is given by $\overline{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

> > We consider the linear data model $Y_i=\theta_1+U_i$ with constant mean $\theta_1$ for $n$ independent observations $y_i,~i=1,\ldots,n$. Show that the least squares estimator of $\theta_1$ is given by the arithmetic mean $\overline{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$.

Hello, do not know if I got it right, but I think here it is meant
$$
Y=X\theta_1+U
$$
with
$$
Y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\\vdots\\y_n\end{pmatrix}, X=\begin{pmatrix}1\\\vdots\\ 1\end{pmatrix}, U=\begin{pmatrix}U_1\\\vdots\\U_n\end{pmatrix},
$$
whereat $E(U_i)=0, i=1,\ldots,n$.

In our reading we had that the least square estimator for $\theta$ (we called this estimator $\hat{\theta}$) is given by
$$
\hat{\theta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty.
$$
Here it is
$$
(X^TX)^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n}\end{pmatrix},~~X^Ty=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i\end{pmatrix}, (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i=\hat{\theta_1}.
$$
Is that the whole proof?

Miro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question meant you to go back a step. I.e. start with finding $\hat{\theta}$ which minimises $\sum (y_i-\theta)^2$

Comment: We did that in the reading!